# Devtron is unable to load the processes graph

Tags: javascript, electron, node-modules

I am learning to use [Eletron](https://electronjs.org) and I found very useful this debugging tool: [Devtron](https://electronjs.org/devtron).

But it not works and I don't know if it is a bug or I am not using it correctly.

The installation guide from Devtron's website says:

```
# Install Devtron
$ npm install --save-dev devtron

// Run the following from the Console tab of your app's DevTools
require('devtron').install()
// You should now see a Devtron tab added to the DevTools
```

I did it correctly, and now I can see the *Devtron tab* on the Inspector panel:

[image]

But when I run my [Quick Start](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/quick-start) by `npm start` application the graph does not show and I get following errors in the shell:

[image]

[image]

I looked for the *faulty* function in ./devtron/out/index.js

```
 loadGraph () {
    modules.getRenderModules().then((mainModule) => {
      this.tableDescription.classList.add('hidden')
      const suffix = this.getTabLabelSuffix(mainModule)
      this.renderProcessTab.textContent = `Renderer Process ${suffix}`
      this.renderRequireRows.innerHTML = ''
      if (this.rootRenderView) this.rootRenderView.destroy()
      this.rootRenderView = new ModuleView(mainModule, this.renderRequireRows)
      this.rootRenderView.select()
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error('Loading render modules failed')
      console.error(error.stack || error)
    })
```

But can't understand what wrong.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Judging from the issues on GitHub, devtron is no longer maintained and not compatible with more recent versions of Electron https://github.com/electron/devtron/issues/109 – the last release is more than 2 years ago.